# Is it possible to assign in lua a separately defined function to an object as the object's method with access to 'self'?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to assign a separately defined function to an object as the object's method and be able to access this object's `self`?

```
SomeObject = {name = "Jack"}

function someExternalFunction ()
    print(self.name)        
end
SomeObject.someMethodName = someExternalFunction -- this is just an example
SomeObject:someMethodName() --> prints "Jack"
```

Comment: Thank you. Corrected, should be `self.name` of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is not magic or anything all that special.
When you call a function like `object:method()` this is just sugar syntax for `object.method(object)`.

When you define a function as `function object:method()` it implicitly has a first arg called self so the definition is equivalant to `function object.method(self)`

so all you need to do is, define your external function properly and it will work fine.

```lua
SomeObject = {name = "Jack"}

function someExternalFunction(self)
    print(self.name)        
end
SomeObject.someMethodName = someExternalFunction
SomeObject:someMethodName() --prints "Jack"
```

Comment: @Eggon, just note that you can use any name for that first parameter. you don't have to use `self`. I personally would find it misleading to use self in a function that is not defined as a table field.

Comment: @Piglet Thanks. In this case the sole purpose of the function is to be interchanged with the original one, so it would be actually confusing not to use self there. :)